# "Please install following missing utilities: cvs" Yocto build issue

Tags: server, system-installation, system

I'm trying to build a linux image following the Yocto build ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNLYanJAQ3s&t=265s)). 
I keep getting the error:

```
Please install following missing utilities: cvs
```

I don't really understand this error because I'm doing it on my local machine, I've retrieved all the files I needed from the Yocto server

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu? if not the please post it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'm building it on an ubuntu machine, that's why i posted it here

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much information about this but i found the answer. You have to download the necessary files, you do this by typing

```
sudo apt-get install cvs
```